# Erro ao tentar se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL local

Tags: java, android, mysql

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar acessar um banco de dados MySQL local, estou seguindo [este tutorial](http://inovarecriar.com/home/android-conectando-ao-mysql-com-asynctask/).

Meu arquivo `MysqlConnect.java`:

```java
package br.com.alerts;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class MysqlConnect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final static String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1:3306/table";
    private final static String user = "root";
    private final static String pass = "159357";
    private Connection con;
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public MysqlConnect(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public Boolean isConected() {
        try
        {
            if (con == null)
            {
                return false;
            } else {
                return (!this.con.isClosed());
            } 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean connect() {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            Log.d("","Conectado com sucesso!");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isConected();
    }
    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            con.close();
            con.isClosed();
            Log.d("","Desconectado!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
        dialog.setMessage("Aguarde... conectando ao banco de dados...");
        dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        connect();
        return isConected();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Classe que está iniciando a conexão, `MysqlConnectActivity`:

```java
package br.com.alerts;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MysqlConnectActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button btInputHost, btInputPort, btInputDataBase, btInputUser, btInputPassword, btstartConnect;

    String host, port, database, user, password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mysqlconnect);

        btInputHost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonInputHostConnect);
        btInputPort = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonInputPortConnect);
        btInputDataBase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonInputDataBaseConnect);
        btInputUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonInputUserConnect);
        btInputPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonInputPasswordConnect);
        btstartConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonStartConnect);

        btInputHost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder inputHost = new AlertDialog.Builder(MysqlConnectActivity.this);
                inputHost.setTitle("Host:");

                final EditText et_inputHost = new EditText(MysqlConnectActivity.this);
                inputHost.setView(et_inputHost);

                inputHost.setNeutralButton("Cancelar", null);

                inputHost.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                   
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        host = et_inputHost.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(MysqlConnectActivity.this, "Host Entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                inputHost.show();
            }
        });
        btInputPort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder inputPort = new AlertDialog.Builder(MysqlConnectActivity.this);
                inputPort.setTitle("Port:");

                final EditText et_inputPort = new EditText(MysqlConnectActivity.this);
                inputPort.setView(et_inputPort);

                inputPort.setNeutralButton("Cancelar", null);

                inputPort.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                   
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        port = et_inputPort.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(MysqlConnectActivity.this, "Port Entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                inputPort.show();
            }
        });
        btInputDataBase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder inputDataBase = new AlertDialog.Builder(MysqlConnectActivity.this);
                inputDataBase.setTitle("DataBase:");

                final EditText et_inputDataBase = new EditText(MysqlConnectActivity.this);
                inputDataBase.setView(et_inputDataBase);

                inputDataBase.setNeutralButton("Cancelar", null);

                inputDataBase.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                   
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        database = et_inputDataBase.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(MysqlConnectActivity.this, "DataBase Entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                inputDataBase.show();
            }
        });
        btInputUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder inputUser = new AlertDialog.Builder(MysqlConnectActivity.this);
                inputUser.setTitle("DataBase:");

                final EditText et_inputUser = new EditText(MysqlConnectActivity.this);
                inputUser.setView(et_inputUser);

                inputUser.setNeutralButton("Cancelar", null);

                inputUser.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                   
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        user = et_inputUser.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(MysqlConnectActivity.this, "User Entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                inputUser.show();
            }
        });
        btInputPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder inputPassword = new AlertDialog.Builder(MysqlConnectActivity.this);
                inputPassword.setTitle("DataBase:");

                final EditText et_inputPassword = new EditText(MysqlConnectActivity.this);
                inputPassword.setView(et_inputPassword);

                inputPassword.setNeutralButton("Cancelar", null);

                inputPassword.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                   
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        password = et_inputPassword.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(MysqlConnectActivity.this, "Password Entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                inputPassword.show();
            }
        });
        btstartConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {           
                MysqlConnect con = new MysqlConnect(MysqlConnectActivity.this);

                TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ButtonTextTest);
                tvText.setText("Aguardando...");

                try {
                    if (con.execute().get()){
                        if (con.isConected())
                        {
                            tvText.setText("Conectado!");
                        } else {
                            tvText.setText("Falha na Conexao!");
                        }               
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

E a minha LogCat:

```
02-14 22:18:16.352: W/System.err(3822): java.sql.SQLException: Unable to connect to any hosts due to exception: java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.1 (port 3306): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
02-14 22:18:16.353: W/System.err(3822): ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
02-14 22:18:16.353: W/System.err(3822): java.net.SocketException
02-14 22:18:16.353: W/System.err(3822): MESSAGE: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.1 (port 3306): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
02-14 22:18:16.353: W/System.err(3822): STACKTRACE:
02-14 22:18:16.354: W/System.err(3822): java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.1 (port 3306): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
02-14 22:18:16.354: W/System.err(3822):     at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:143)
02-14 22:18:16.354: W/System.err(3822):     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:225)
02-14 22:18:16.509: W/System.err(3822):     at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1805)
02-14 22:18:16.509: W/System.err(3822):     at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
02-14 22:18:16.549: W/System.err(3822):     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
02-14 22:18:16.549: W/System.err(3822):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
02-14 22:18:16.549: W/System.err(3822):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
02-14 22:18:16.551: W/System.err(3822):     at br.com.alerts.MysqlConnect.connect(MysqlConnect.java:41)
02-14 22:18:16.551: W/System.err(3822):     at br.com.alerts.MysqlConnect.doInBackground(MysqlConnect.java:66)
02-14 22:18:16.551: W/System.err(3822):     at br.com.alerts.MysqlConnect.doInBackground(MysqlConnect.java:1)
02-14 22:18:16.552: W/System.err(3822):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-14 22:18:16.552: W/System.err(3822):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-14 22:18:16.552: W/System.err(3822):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-14 22:18:16.552: W/System.err(3822):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-14 22:18:16.554: W/System.err(3822):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-14 22:18:16.554: W/System.err(3822):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-14 22:18:16.617: W/System.err(3822): ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
02-14 22:18:16.618: W/System.err(3822):     at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1875)
02-14 22:18:16.619: W/System.err(3822):     at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
02-14 22:18:16.619: W/System.err(3822):     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
02-14 22:18:16.619: W/System.err(3822):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
02-14 22:18:16.619: W/System.err(3822):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
02-14 22:18:16.619: W/System.err(3822):     at br.com.alerts.MysqlConnect.connect(MysqlConnect.java:41)
02-14 22:18:16.620: W/System.err(3822):     at br.com.alerts.MysqlConnect.doInBackground(MysqlConnect.java:66)
02-14 22:18:16.620: W/System.err(3822):     at br.com.alerts.MysqlConnect.doInBackground(MysqlConnect.java:1)
02-14 22:18:16.620: W/System.err(3822):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-14 22:18:16.620: W/System.err(3822):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-14 22:18:16.620: W/System.err(3822):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-14 22:18:16.621: W/System.err(3822):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-14 22:18:16.621: W/System.err(3822):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-14 22:18:16.621: W/System.err(3822):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-14 22:18:16.639: I/Choreographer(3822): Skipped 7071 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-14 22:18:17.890: I/Choreographer(3822): Skipped 110 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

O MySQL esta rodando na minha máquina na porta 3606, agora não sei se existe firewall e se o MySQL está habilitado para receber conexão externa.

Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Já verificou se o MySQL está rodando? Existe algum firewall rodando no servidor? Seu MySQL está na mesma rede do seu Android? Seu MySQL está configurado para receber conexões externas? Seu MySQL está ouvindo na porta 3306? Se puder editar sua pergunta e informar tudo isso fica mais fácil de  localizar o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Configure seu Banco conforme esse tutorial:

```
#1 – Edite o arquivo: 
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
#2 – Altere a seguinte linha:
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
#Deixando assim:
#bind-address = 0.0.0.0
#3 – Reinicie o Mysql
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
#4 – Vamos agora dar GRANT no usuário root, logue no mysql:
mysql -u root -p
#5 – Após se logar, digite o seguinte comando:
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@’%’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘sua_senha’;
```

Caso não encontre o arquivo de configuração, localize ele pelo cmd/terminal

use `find -name  'my.cnf'` em ambiente unix

use `dir my.cnf /s"`

Fonte: [habilitando-acesso-remoto](http://jf.eti.br/habilitando-acesso-remoto-ao-servidor-mysql/)

Caso não funcione, existe a possibilidade do seu provedor de internet fornecer algum tipo de bloqueio de portas, no caso da netvirtual por exemplo não é possível retirar, se você precisa fazer testes em uma rede diferente, use algum serviço como os da [AWS](http://%20aws.amazon.com/pt/) você pode usar um conjunto de serviços gratuitamente por um ano.

Caso queira fazer o teste com seu telefone na mesma rede, ainda é possível, deixe o telefone no wifi e desligue o 3G, se não funcionar seu roteador está com a porta bloqueada, entre na pagina de configuração do seu roteador (se estiver usando linux ache o ip usando route -n) 
abra a porta 3606 e teste novamente.

Links para instalação do Mysql [Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/),[Linux](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Instalando-o-Servidor-MySQL-no-Linux)

Comment: Cara, eu estou começando a achar que me equivoquei ao tentar instalar MySQL na minha maquina, eu inatalei MySQL Comunity que consegui no site MySQL, esta certo?

Comment: Sim, Se estiver usando Windows, vá na pasta  c:\Windows\my.ini ou c:\my.cnf, e segue os mesmos passos do tutorial, não esqueça de reiniciar o mysql.

Comment: Desculpa mas poderia me passar um tutorial de como instalar o MySQL? nao tive exito ao procurar essas duas pasta que voce citou acima @Isvaldo Fernandes

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta colocando links para instalação no windows

Comment: Eu tentei fazer isso, so que aconteçe que nao consegui localizar os arquivos my.ini ou my.cnf, estou usando a versao 5.6...

Comment: Como localizo essas informações? Url: jdbc:mysql://<ip>:<porta>/<database>";